# how to store database query result in a variable in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to store my database query result in my view section in a variable.I am trying but not work.

My View code

```
$cd=''.base_url().'/video/series/';
$count = count($cd);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
{
  print'"'.$cd[$i][1].'",';  

}
```

My Controller code

```
public function series() {

    $result= $this->video_model->series_list();

    return $result;


}
```

My Model Code

```
function series_list()
{

    $string = trim($this->input->get_post('term'));
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM `series` WHERE name LIKE '%".$string."%'");


    return $query->row_array();
```

}

```
$cd=''.base_url().'/video/series/'; not get any array data ,only get blank data
```

Comment: Can you show us the database query and how you're trying to store the result?

Comment: And the result of `var_dump($query); exit();` is?

Answer (score 2):

You can get post variable value in controller only. But you trying to get it in model. That's wrong.

Controller:

```
public function series() {
$string = trim($this->input->get_post('term'));    
$data['result']= $this->video_model->series_list($string);
$this->load->view('folder/filename', $data);  
// in your case i think folder= video and filename = series
// in this way you can pass value from controller to view

}
```

Model:

```
function series_list($string = null)
{
    if($string != ''){
       $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM `series` WHERE name LIKE '%".$string."%'");
       return $query->row_array();
    }
    else
       return false;
}
```

View:

```
<?php
 var_dump($data);
?>
```

you can get your resultset in view and can play with it as you want.

Comment: @NaincyGupta you need to keep the result variable inside an array and then pass array in view.

Comment: @k10gaurav: he is trying to get post variable in model which is wrong.

Comment: hmm... right @NaincyGupta but variable accessibility requires to be in array so that if I have n number of variables in controller they would be accessible in view.

Comment: @k10gaurav: I have made changes in my code accordingly. :)

Comment: @NaincyGupta me too. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass variable inside some array(in view method) so that all variables inside common array would be accessible on view page

Controller code would be

```
public function series() 
{
  $inputData     =trim(strip_tags($this->input->get_post('term')));
  $data['result']= $this->video_model->series_list($inputData);
  $this->load->view('directory/viewpage',$data); //$data is array with all variables inside it
}
```

Model code would be

```
function series_list($data)
{
 $string = $data;
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM `series` WHERE name LIKE '%".$string."%'");
 if( $query->num_rows>0)
 {
  return $query->row_array();
 }
 else
 {
   return false;
 }
}
```

View code would be

```
<?php
     if(isset($result)&&($result!=''))
    {
      echo "<pre/>";
      print_r($result); // Or var_dump($result);
    }
?>
```